# Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Gdje_si_veceras\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, cryptojs

I work with React.js and Node.js and want to upload photo from myComputer to server. First step is to upload photo to server. I got whole code and code works but there is an error:
[image: ERROR PIC]

I follow the steps to solve this error. I made folder webpack and inside of that folder I made file webpack.config.js and add this line: 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
[image: ADD WEBPACK.CONFIG.js]
I also install crypto-browserify. And restart the project. The error is still here.
I think that my 'C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Gdje_si_veceras\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist' file dont see my webpack. How to fix that if this is a mistake.

Comment: Which version of `bcryptjs` library are you using?

Comment: version "bcrypt": "^5.1.0", on backend and "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3", on frontend

Comment: There was an error with dependecies. I remove package-lock.json, node-modules and run npm install. Now everything works fine.